# "ERROR: operator does not exist : integer = integer[]" when using "IN" operator in PostgreSQL. Why do I get this error?

Tags: postgresql

### What I'm trying to achieve

First I need to query table `tableY` to get all userids that fulfill the inner WHERE condition. Then I aggregate it into an array of userids with `array_agg(userid)`. Then in the outer query, I need to select users from the `tableX` table with userids that exist inside the array I created before from `tableY`.

### Error

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = integer[]

LINE 2: WHERE 3 IN ((

HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type cast.
```

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM mydb.tableX 
WHERE 3 IN ((
SELECT array_agg(userid) userids FROM
  (
    SELECT 
    DISTINCT(uc.userid), eui.firstname
    FROM mydb.tableY uc 
    JOIN mydb.tableX eui ON uc.userid = eui.auth_userid
    WHERE uc.level = 4 
    AND uc.subjectid = 1
    AND uc.lineid = 5 
    GROUP BY uc.userid, eui.firstname
    ORDER BY eui.firstname
  ) AS userids 
))
```

Btw, I only use the "3" as a hard coded example now to get the query running in the first place.

### Question

Why do I get the error?

Thanks!

Comment: While `IN` can also be used with arrays, `IN (SELECT …)` checks whether any of the results of the subquery match the operand. Just omit the `array_agg(…)` call and it should work.

Comment: Thank you @Bergi . This helped. I just removed the array aggregate and followed the answer below.

Comment: You forgot to add the query and the error message into the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array_agg is useless in this context. It is only significant overhead and in block some possible optimization.

Write just `WHERE d IN (SELECT userid ...`

Note - when you really need to check if some value is in an array, you should to use operator `= ANY()`, but this is not this case:

```
postgres=# SELECT 1 WHERE 1 = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3]);
┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
╞══════════╡
│        1 │
└──────────┘
(1 row)
```